# failed to open stream: Disk quota exceeded godaddy cpanel

Tags: cpan

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEvT4.png)

how to increase this File Usage

Comment: This is not a programming related question. This is a question for GoDaddy, check out their support pages or "Contact Us" options.

Comment: i ask the   support team and upgrade the plan but doesn't work

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Per their web hosting page (https://www.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting#compare) the most number of files you can have on any plan is 250,000. You either need to delete files, or find another host.